# Wagtail query - date range, type selection and limit

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, wagtail

I am trying to make a site with this structure:

```
Home page
  - Organisation (Page model)
    - Event (Page model)
```

Now, on the `Home page` I want to display the events that will be from today, untill seven days ahead, or limited by 10 if there are many. I have given the events these two values:

```
start = models.DateTimeField()
end = models.DateTimeField()
```

, and I would like to sort on `start`.

My first attempt looks like this, but it is not working:

```
def get_context(self, request):
    context = super().get_context(request)
    events = self.get_children().type(Event).filter(date__range=['2018-08-25', '2018-08-31']).live().order_by('start') 
    context['events'] = events
    return context
```

There should also be a limiter in there somewhere, so that it does not return more than 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `self.get_children().type(Event)`, use `Event.objects.child_of(self)`. This is necessary because `get_children` returns objects of type `Page`, the basic record common to all page types. The `type(Event)` clause will limit that queryset to just Event pages, but will still leave them as `Page` objects, where the date field isn't available. By using `Event.objects.child_of(self)`, you ensure that you're using the full `Event` model all the way through the query.

Also, make sure that your filter clause refers to a field that's defined on your model; rather than `date_range`, it should probably be `start_range` or `end_range`. Or, if you want it to return events that are happening at some point in the next 7 days, you're really looking for ones that start before [today + 7 days] and end after today, which would make the filter: `.filter(start__lte='2018-08-31', end__gte='2018-08-25')`

To limit the query to a maximum of 10 items, use Python array slicing notation: `[:10]`

This makes the final `events` line as follows:

```
events = Event.objects.child_of(self).filter(start__lte='2018-08-31', end__gte='2018-08-25').live().order_by('start')[:10]
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you! This seems to be the way to do it. Only thing is that it will only grab the direct decendants of Home, and not the Events under Organisation. Could you explain the __gte and __lte flags or whatever they are? Thank you again :)

Comment: If you want to allow descendants that are not immediate children of `self`, use `descendant_of(self)` instead of `child_of(self)` - or if the location in the tree doesn't matter at all, leave that out completely. For the `lte` / `gte` lookups, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

Comment: Thank you! I have started to read up on Django now, as I see I need to know this to understand Wagtail properly :)